# Memory Issues In Grid Search cv for Image Classification Problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning, gridsearchcv

I am implementing the Grid Search CV with stratified Shuffle Split on a VGG16 Model, I am transforming the data from flow from dataframe into a numpy array to be able to pass them to the grid search cv but I am having memory issues because I am training on 10 000 image. How to fix this problem or there is any other solution to use K fold and implement the hyperparameter tuning on the 5 folds and each time train and fit?

This is my function, train_data is a dataframe and buildodel is the vgg16 model

```
Y = train_data[['label']]

data = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function = preprocess_input)
data_generator = data.flow_from_dataframe(train_data, directory = path,
                x_col = "filename", y_col = "label",
                class_mode = "binary", target_size=(224, 224), batch_size = len(train_data))
  
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn = buildModel, verbose=0)
  
batch_size = [10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
epochs = [10, 50, 100]
optimizer = ['SGD', 'RMSprop', 'Adagrad', 'Adadelta', 'Adam', 'Adamax', 'Nadam']

param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs,optimizer=optimizer)

x = data_generator.next()[0]
print(x.shape)
y = data_generator.next()[1]
print(y.shape)

stratifiedSplit = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.3)

kfold_splits = 5
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model,  
                n_jobs=-1, 
                verbose=1,
                return_train_score=True,
                cv=stratifiedSplit,
                param_grid=param_grid,)

grid_result = grid.fit(x, y, ) #callbacks=[tbCallBack]

cross_val_score(grid, x, y, cv=stratifiedSplit)

print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

Comment: Try using a lower range of Epochs! I had this issue in the past and when I narrowed the epochs range, it showed the results.

Comment: @Salma but the memory error is getting before making the grid.fit, because I have 10 000 image.